# Retrieve latitude and longitude of a sample of coordinates from Wikidata using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to retrieve samples of coordinates in Wikidata via SPARQL but am having a very difficult time trying to achieve it. I would want to get only a single pair of coordinates per place and display the result in a column, and the latitude and longitude of the said coordinates sample in their own columns.

The following code ([link to WQS](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fplace%20%3FplaceLabel%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Ftemp1%29%20AS%20%3Fcoords_sample%29%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20p%3AP31%20%3FinstanceOf.%0A%20%20%3FinstanceOf%20ps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3A279%2a%20wd%3AQ2039348.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoords.%0A%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20p%3AP625%20%3Ftemp1.%0A%20%20%3Ftemp1%20psv%3AP625%20%3Ftemp2.%0A%20%20%3Ftemp2%20wikibase%3AgeoLatitude%20%3Flat.%0A%20%20%3Ftemp2%20wikibase%3AgeoLongitude%20%3Flong.%20%0A%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fplace%20%3FplaceLabel%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%0A%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FplaceLabel)) I use below works, but it does not get the coordinates values labels in `Point(5.936111111 51.21)` format. When I replace `p:P625` with `wdt:P625`, no items are retrieved. Additionally, **Borculo** ([Q1025685](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1025685)) appears twice in the results with two unique coordinates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?place ?placeLabel (SAMPLE(?temp1) AS ?coords_sample) ?lat ?long {

  ?place p:P31 ?instanceOf.
  ?instanceOf ps:P31/wdt:279* wd:Q2039348.
  
  ?place p:P625 ?temp1.
  ?temp1 psv:P625 ?temp2.
  ?temp2 wikibase:geoLatitude ?lat.
  ?temp2 wikibase:geoLongitude ?long. 

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} GROUP BY ?place ?placeLabel ?lat ?long

ORDER BY ?placeLabel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ps:P625` for obtaining the coordinates in the desired format (see also the [manual on Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/WIKIDATA_Precision,_Units_and_Coordinates#Coordinates)).

Also, it is not sufficient to sample the coordinates statement if you also group by `?lat` and `?long`. Hence, you'd better to sample it in a subquery.

Final result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?place ?placeLabel ?coords ?lat ?long {
  ?place p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:279* wd:Q2039348 ;
         p:P625 ?coords_sample .
  {
    SELECT (SAMPLE(?coords_stmt) AS ?coords_sample) {
      ?place p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:279* wd:Q2039348 ;
             p:P625 ?coords_stmt .
    } GROUP BY ?place
  }
  ?coords_sample ps:P625 ?coords;
                 psv:P625 [
                   wikibase:geoLatitude ?lat;
                   wikibase:geoLongitude ?long
                 ] .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?placeLabel
```

Comment: For the difference between `wdt:` and `p:` you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023098 and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase_RDF_Format#Predicates

Comment: thank you for the information. However, I opted to use the `SAMPLE()` code to get only a single pair of coordinates since not only Borculo (`Q1025685`) was appearing in the results multiple times, but also several (about 300 I guess) places like Gasselte ([Q2015118](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2015118)),  Hoevelaken ([Q3056778](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3056778)), and Hoogmade ([Q2106954](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2106954)). The results of the code you have provided still show multiple entries of a single unique item.

Comment: @JAT86 I edited my answer, please check if the new query satisfies your requirements.